# Office 365 - Remove alias from shared mailbox

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange, alias, shared-mailbox

I have an issue on O365.
My customer would like to use the shared mailbox I created as a distribution group.

So I thought "ok, lets create an alias test2@test.com on the shared mailbox, put it as standard SMTP address and then remove the original test@test.com that became an alias"
It doesn't work.
I tried with the admin portal, the exchange portal and powershell.

I tried to change the name so it's the same as the alias but it doesn't help.

Right now I have about 10 users who are permitted on the shared mailbox and one redirection.
One weird thing is that now they can't send mails.

The powershell command I used is:
Set-Mailbox test2 -EmailAddresses @{remove='test@test.com'}

I get no error, as if the command executed properly. But when I do a check with:
Get-Mailbox test2 | select -expand emailaddresses alias
It still shows

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Finally I went on the Azure Active Directory and change the "user name" not just the "name" Then I had to go to exchange console and remove the alias from the shared mailbox Then I could create my Distribution group with the same name... Pfiu